# Can an insulator become a conductor at superconductive temperatures?

Tags: electrons, superconductivity, insulators

Can an insulator become a conductor at superconductive temperatures? As a part of electric resistivity is physical opposition to the stream of particles would an insulator having its nuclei inert in place at those temperatures lose a part of its electrical resistence?

Comment: Are you asking whether there are materials experiencing insulator-to-metal transition when going from high to low temperatures?